# Logical OR not functioning

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, logical-operators

Is there something wrong with the code? Because, when I am removing the OR in the statement, I am getting the right output, but when I'm inserting the `||` the output that I'm getting is what's in the statement where the OR operator is located.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#select1").change(function(){
            if($(event.target).val() == 'AK'){
                    $("#select2").change(function(){
                        if($(event.target).val() == 'LLC'){
                            $('#txt6').val('250.00');
                        }else{
                            $('#txt6').val('250.00');
                        }
                    }); 
                }else if($(event.target).val() == 'AR'  || 'CO' || 'HI' || 'IA' || 'MS'){
                    $("#select2").change(function(){
                        if($(event.target).val() == 'LLC'){
                            $('#txt6').val('50.00');
                        } else{
                            $('#txt6').val('50.00');
                        }
                    });
            }else
            if($(event.target).val() == 'AZ'){
                    $("#select2").change(function(){
                        if($(event.target).val() == 'LLC'){
                            $('#txt6').val('50.00');
                        } else{
                            $('#txt6').val('60.00');
                        }
                    });
                }else
}else
        if($(event.target).val() == 'WI'){
                $("#select2").change(function(){
                    if($(event.target).val() == 'LLC'){
                        $('#txt6').val('103.00');
                    } else{
                        $('#txt6').val('103.00');
                    }
                });
            }else
        {
            $("#select2").change(function(){
                    if($(event.target).val() == 'LLC'){
                        $('#txt6').val('186.00');
                    } else{
                        $('#txt6').val('186.00');
                    }
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this a valid if statement? $(event.target).val() == 'AR'  || 'CO' || 'HI' || 'IA' || 'MS'. Shouldn't it be $(event.target).val() == 'AR'  || $(event.target).val() == 'CO' || $(event.target).val() == 'HI' || $(event.target).val() == 'IA' || $(event.target).val() == 'MS'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
$(event.target).val() == 'AR'  || 'CO' || 'HI' || 'IA' || 'MS'
```

As it translates to this:

```
($(event.target).val() == 'AR')  || ('CO') || ('HI') || ('IA') || ('MS')
```

Which translates to this:

```
(<true/false>)  || true || true || true || true
```

What you need is:

```
$(event.target).val() == 'AR'  ||
$(event.target).val() == 'CO' || 
$(event.target).val() == 'HI' || 
$(event.target).val() == 'IA' || 
$(event.target).val() == 'MS'
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
var allowed = ['AR', 'CO', 'HI', 'IA', 'MS'];

if ($.inArray($(event.target).val(), allowed)) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(event.target).val() == 'AR'  || 'CO' || 'HI' || 'IA' || 'MS'
```

Should be

```
$(event.target).val() == 'AR'  || $(event.target).val() == 'CO' || $(event.target).val() == 'HI' || $(event.target).val() == 'IA' || $(event.target).val() == 'MS'
```

That's a small mistake people do, they think correctly but write wrong. Because normally we think:

```
if value equals to xyz or pqr
```

and we write

```
if(value == "xyz" || "pqr")
```

which is wrong, we did this mistake because we were in flow of words. It should be

```
if(value == "xyz" || value == "pqr")
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
 }else if($(event.target).val() == 'AR'  || 'CO' || 'HI' || 'IA' || 'MS'){
```

is in error.

Need something like

```
}else if($(event.target).val() == 'AR'  || $(event.target).val() == 'CO' || $(event.target).val() =='HI ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`||` joins separate and independent boolean conditions, not string values.

You may want to do this instead:

```
if ( /^(AR|CO|HI|IA|MS)$/.test( $(event.target).val() ) )
```

Comment: This is not the same as equality - perhaps `if ( /^(AR|CO|HI|IA|MS)$/.test( $(event.target).val() ) )` would be better